# Track affiliates across multiple domains

Tags: wordpress, nopcommerce, affiliate, affiliates

I have a website for marketing & product details that is setup on Wordpress on a different domain. And a shop is hosted on another domain which accepts orders, process payment & every other e-commerce order processing. This is on a nopCommerce website.

I want to start affiliate marketing and build an affiliate network that would essentially link to the product site built on wordpress. However, as orders are processed by nopCommerce, I'm not sure how it will be able to track affiliates converted to buyer?

I need something that makes it easy to track affiliates across both sites. I'm open to your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: are you using any affiliate software?

Comment: No, I'm not using any affiliate software as of now.

Comment: nopCommerce has built-in support for Affiliate. Have you tried that? :)

Comment: you could also take a look at the other options - e-junkie, clickbank, shareasell ...

Comment: @wooncherk, Yes, but that doesn't work with our main site being on Wordpress. I need something that can track visitors across marketing site build on Wordpress and Cart that is on nopCommerce to track completed orders. Any idea?

Comment: @Prasad, thank you for suggestions.. I'm already evaluating shareasell, will also look at e-junkie & clickbank. Thank you